# Trigonometric polynomial derivative upper bound

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $P$ be a trig poly of degree $N$ on the torus $\mathbb T$. Prove that
$$\Vert P' \Vert_\infty \lesssim N\Vert P \Vert_\infty.$$
I'm not sure how to approach this problem, though I feel like some Fourier approach is probably in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, we can show that $ \|P_N'\|\leq 4\pi N\|P_N\|_{\infty} $. To prove this, we firstly claim that $ P_N'(x) $ can be represented by
$$
\frac{P_N'(x)}{2\pi iN}=((e^{-2\pi iN(\cdot)}P_N)*F_{N-1})(x)e^{2\pi iNx}-((e^{2\pi iN(\cdot)}P_N)*F_{N-1})(x)e^{-2\pi iNx}.
$$
If this claim is true, the improvement for the results can be easily got that
$$
\left\|\frac{P'}{2\pi iN}\right\|_{\infty}\leq \|e^{-2\pi iN(\cdot)}P_N\|_{\infty}\|F_{N-1}\|_{1}+\|e^{2\pi iN(\cdot)}P_N\|_{\infty}\|F_{N-1}\|_{1}\leq 2\|P_N\|_{\infty},
$$
which completes the proof. Now we will show the claim. By the linearity, we only need to verify the result for $ P_N(x)=ae^{2\pi ikx} $. Indeed,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1e^{-2\pi iN(x-y)}\cdot ae^{2\pi ik(x-y)}F_{N-1}(y)e^{2\pi iNx}dy&=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\frac{ka }{N}e^{2\pi ikx}&\text{ if }&k>0,\\
&0&\text{ if }&k\leq 0,
\end{aligned}\right.\\
\int_0^1e^{2\pi iN(x-y)}\cdot ae^{2\pi ik(x-y)}F_{N-1}(y)e^{-2\pi iNx}dy&=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\frac{ka}{N}e^{2\pi ikx}&\text{ if }&k<0,\\
&0&\text{ if }&k\geq 0.
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: What is $F_{N-1}$ standing for? I am pretty sure it is Fourier related, but i dont know what it is exactly

Comment: @Salfalur This is the Fejer kernel.