# How to prove this inequality about trigonometric polynomial？

Tags: inequality, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

Problem statement:
Define $T_n(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}{(a_k\cos kx+b_k\sin kx)}$ be a real valued trigonometric polynomial on $[-\pi,\pi]$.
Prove that
$$\mathop{max}\limits_{-\pi\le x \le \pi}{|{T_n}'(x) |}\le n^2\mathop{max}\limits_{-\pi\le x \le \pi}{|{T_n}(x) |}$$
It seems difficult to calculate the maximum of a trigonometric polynomial. And I find it hard to establish a connection between two maximum values. How to prove this inequality? I would appreciate if you can give some help.

Comment: You may have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4776137/trigonometric-polynomial-derivative-upper-bound/4776607?noredirect=1#comment10187840_4776607). The same result was proven there, but with an $n$ instead of $n^2$.

Comment: It is related to the famous Bernstein’s inequality for trigonometric polynomials.